# Unable to get unserialize data from wordpress post meta

Tags: mysql, json, wordpress

I want to display post meta values in wordpress which is storing in database as per below format:
`{s:13:"default_price";s:6:"943943";s:4:"type";s:21:"mwb_wgm_default_price";s:8:"template";i:4751;s:14:"by_default_tem";b:1;}`
My  `meta_key`  is  `mwb_pricing`  and i want to extract and display  `meta_value`  as  `default_price`  which is  `943943`  but unable to do so.
Here is my code:

```
$post_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id ); // array of all meta fields 
$mydata = $post_meta['mwb_pricing'][0];
$mydata = unserialize($mydata);
echo $mydata[13];
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier then that, you can just do:

```
$mydata  = get_post_meta($post_id,'mwb_pricing',true);
```

Wp will take care of unserializing data for you. See [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

If you need to access your data after pulling them out of DB you can do this:

```
$defaultPrice = $mydata["default_price"];
```

to get the value of "default_price"

Comment: Thank you for quick response but when i echo `$mydata` this results `"Array"`

Comment: Don't echo it, use var_dump. For example to have 'default_price you would need to do $mydata["default_price"]. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thank you @Diego. you save my day :)